# How to pass a variable value as an argument to -command option in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wrote a piece of code where menus are created only if certain file is present in directory, once file is found, menu(s) are installed in tcl UI.
i am extracting a file name and read it line by line to install a menu, it works well but i wanted to open this file for viewing when newly installed menu button is clicked in UI.

I tried -command as `{exec emacs $rundir/$line}` but it didnt work.

```
        $rundir is /home/abc
        $line is filename= example.log
```

Here goes my code:

```
proc get_lib2cpf_results {} {  ## procedure
type_run    
global rundir typep logfile line
cd $rundir
if {[file exists $rundir/check_syntax_$typep.sh] == 0 } {
tk_dialog .dialog1 "File didn't exist" info 0 OK
} else {

exec cat $rundir/check_syntax_$typep.sh | awk {{print $13}} > file_$typep.txt    ### finding a file in a rundir
.mbar.dm  add cascade -label "LOGFILE(s)" -menu .mbar.dm.sb -underline 1
menu .mbar.dm.sb   #### creating a menu entry
set f [open $rundir/file_$typep.txt]  ### reading file line by line
while {1} {
set line [gets $f]
if {[eof $f]} {
close $f
break
}
puts "Read line: $line"
puts "Logfile is present at $rundir/$line"
.mbar.dm.sb add command -label $line -underline 0 -command { exec emacs $rundir/$line] }              ### adding menu entry based on $line
}
}
}
```

Please let me know if its possible to achieve this ?  any alternate approach will be appreciated.